# Converting Celsius to Fahrenheit using variables C or F

Tags: java, input

Im creating a program that will convert from Celsius to Fahrenheit and vice versa. I would like the user to input the temperature then C or F for which temperature it is. The issue I'm having is with the input being C or F. can you do if (input == 'F') then have it convert?

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String [] args) 
    { 
     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
String tempScale = ""; 

System.out.print("Enter the current outside temperature: "); 
double temps = scan.nextDouble(); 

System.out.println("Celsius or Fahrenheight (C or F): "); 
int input = scan.nextInt(); 

if (input == F) { 
// convert F to C 
temps = (temps-32) * 5/9.0; 
tempScale = "Celsius."; 
} else if (input == 'C') { 
// convert C to F 
temps = (temps * 9/5.0) +32; 
tempScale = "Fahrenheit."; 
}//end if/else 

System.out.println("The answer = "+temps+" degrees "+tempScale); 

}//end main() 
}//end class
```

Comment: Have you tried testing it?

Comment: "What's wrong?" (Hint: You don't want to read 'C' or 'F' as an `int` - perhaps as a String? And then see `"F".equals(whatIRead)` ..)

Comment: Why not have a try on compiling it and run it?

Comment: You should get `java.util.InputMismatchException`. Check this line `int input = scan.nextInt();` and your conditions for ex. `if (input == F)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
 public class JavaApplication {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
           Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
           double celsius, fahrenheit;
           System.out.print("Enter a temperature in Celsius: ");
           celsius = sc.nextDouble();
           fahrenheit = 32 + (celsius * 9 / 5);
           System.out.println(celsius +" ºC = " + fahrenheit + " ºF");
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hear is the code You are Looking For.

```
package stackoverflow.java.Answers;

/*
Program for
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18971591/converting-celsius-to-fahrenheit-using-variables-c-or-f
*/

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Temp_Convert{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        print(" === Converting Temperature ===\n");
        convertTemperature();
    }

    private static void convertTemperature() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        print("\nEnter 1 for Fahrenheit to Celsius"
                + "\nEnter 2 for Celsius to Fahrenheit"
                + "\nSomething else to Exit." + "\nYour Option:");
        int selection = input.nextInt();
        if (selection == 1) {
            print("Enter a degree in Fahrenheit:");
            far2cel();
        } else if (selection == 2) {
            print("Enter a degree in Celsius:");
            cel2far();
        } else {
            print("Bye..");
        }
    }

    private static void cel2far() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Double celsius = input.nextDouble();
        print(celsius + " celsius is " + ((celsius * 9 / 5.0) + 32)
                + " Fahrenheit");
        convertTemperature();
    }

    private static void far2cel() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        Double Fahrenheit = input.nextDouble();
        print(Fahrenheit + " Fahrenheit is " + ((Fahrenheit - 32) * (5 / 9.0))
                + " celsius");
        convertTemperature();
    }

    private static void print(String string) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.print("\n" + string);
    }
}
```

---

### **And Output is.**

=== Converting Temperature ===

Enter 1 for Fahrenheit to Celsius
Enter 2 for Celsius to Fahrenheit
Something else to Exit.
Your Option:1

Enter a degree in Fahrenheit:200

200.0 Fahrenheit is 93.33333333333334 celsius

Enter 1 for Fahrenheit to Celsius
Enter 2 for Celsius to Fahrenheit
Something else to Exit.
Your Option:2

Enter a degree in Celsius:8754

8754.0 celsius is 15789.2 Fahrenheit

Enter 1 for Fahrenheit to Celsius
Enter 2 for Celsius to Fahrenheit
Something else to Exit.
Your Option:3

Bye..

:)

Answer (score -3):

Well first of all, you can't have "temps = (temps-32) * 5/9.0" because that's like saying
"50 = (50-32) * 5/9.0" it doesn't work. You have to define a NEW temp and label it as such.

Comment: also, you have to define that variable BEFORE the if-else statement =P

Comment: Yes I have.. I'm working on a program just like this now, and it would not work. Once I renamed the variable, it worked.

Comment: Ok, so if int i = 0; i++; print(i); What gets printed? What about int i = 0; i = i + 1; print(i)?

Comment: i = 1 for both. What's your point with this?? This has nothing to do with what the MAIN focus is.

Comment: But  by your logic, saying i = i + 1 is like saying "0 = 0 + 1 it doesn't work"

Comment: because the ; allows you to change it. MATHEMATICALLY the above equation WOULD NOT WORK. Did you not understand me when I said I did the exact same thing and it wouldn't work????

Comment: AND it's a math problem he's (or she's) trying to do. i = i + 1 is allowed in java, but when you're trying to do a math problem and convert numbers like what is trying to be done in this problem, it will not work.

Comment: sure it would, the variable is just being reused. If you say float temp = (temp - 32) * (5.0f / 9); then temp is left with the desired value... no problem there

Comment: do you see "float" above???? I can guarantee that it does not work. It may compile, but when you try to convert the information, it will come out wrong. I am literally looking at this right now.

Comment: No it's not like saying `50 = (50-32) * 5/9.0`. In Java `=`doesn't mean equality, you're assigning a value to the variable. What would `temps = (temps-32) * 5/9.0` do is calculate the right side and then assign it to temp.